# Array of objects being displayed as [object Object] and not as strings in console

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, object, react-native-flatlist

I can't understand why this is happening
I have added sample data manually and then I am pushing some more data later.
Ultimately I want to display the data in a flatlist.
Please help me, This is very important for my project.
Thank yo
Code:

```js
class TasksScreen extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    tasks: [],
  };
  var tempTasks = [
    {
      key: 'abc',
      val: 'abc',
    },
  ];
  var that = this;

  var taskRef = database()
    .ref('/Tasks/' + auth().currentUser.uid)
    .on('value', dataSnapshot => {
      var key = dataSnapshot.key;
      console.log('UID KEY: ' + key);
      dataSnapshot.forEach(childSnaps => {
        var key = childSnaps.key;
        console.log('TASKID KEY: ' + key);
        childSnaps.forEach(taskData => {
          var taskKey = taskData.key;
          var taskVal = taskData.val();
          console.log('taskData KEY: ' + taskKey);
          console.log('taskData VAL: ' + taskVal);
          console.log('taskData.val().title: ' + taskVal);
          tempTasks.push({
            taskTitle: 'title',
            taskDescription: 'description',
            taskDueTime: 'time',
            taskDuedate: 'date',
          });
        });
      });
      console.log('tempTasks: ' + tempTasks);
      that.setState({tasks: tempTasks});
      console.log('STATE TASKS: ' + that.state.tasks);
    });
}
```

[image]

Comment: `"" + {}` will always result as `[object object]` so instead of concatenating values, you should pass them as separate argument, i,e `console.log('str', object)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are concatening string, the object's `toString` method is called, which returns '[Object object]'. You could replace your `+` with a coma `,` to evaluate each variable in your `console.log` individually. :

```js
let object = {
    title: 'test1',
    count: 10
}

// concatenation
console.log('object : ' + object);

// individual evaluation.
console.log('object : ', object);
```

Answer (score 1):

`"" + {}` will always result as `[object object]` ( Because of string concatenation ) so instead of concatenating values, you should pass them as separate argument, i,e `console.log('str', object)`, if you need it as a single concatenated string you can use **`JSON.stringify`** and then concat them

```js
let obj = {
  a: '123',
}

console.log("String" + obj)
console.log("String", obj)
console.log("String" + JSON.stringify(obj))
```